# Error autoincrementador automatico Netbeans 8.2, Apache Derby 10.14.2

Tags: sql, netbeans-8.2, derby, autoincremento

Al usar Xampp 7.4.1, Netbeans 8.2, MySQL Conector 5.1.47; el autoincrementador combinado de letras y números funciona de manera correcta. Este código fue copiado del canal de Youtube "Tutus Funny", y creo que hizo un gran trabajo el autor.

```
Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;               
    public void AutoID()
    {          
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/piloto1db","root","");
            Statement s = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select MAX(uno_id) from uno");            
            rs.next();
            rs.getString("MAX(uno_id)");
            if (rs.getString("MAX(uno_id)") == null) 
            {   tCliId.setText("CR001");     }
            else
            {   
                long id = Long.parseLong(rs.getString("MAX(uno_id)").substring(2,rs.getString("MAX(uno_id)").length()));
                id++;
                tCliId.setText("CR"+String.format("%03d", id));
            }                          
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VentanaFactor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VentanaFactor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }   
    }
```

Así es como luce el código al ejecutar el proyecto de Netbeans:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, pues, Estoy intentando hacer lo mismo usando el SGBD Embebido Apache Derby.
Para esto, estoy usando: ApacheDerby 10.14.2 y Netbeans 8.2.
Pero me genera errores en el autoincrementador y no funciona.

Me genera el siguiente error: "No exist column MAX(piloto."clientes"."cli_id").".

Creo que no estoy haciendo las consultas de manera adecuada.

```
Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    String murl   = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/";
    String mdb    = "Prueba1Derby";
    String muser  = "piloto";
    String mpass  = "piloto";                
    public void AutoID()
    {
        try {                        
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");            
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(murl+mdb,muser,mpass);
            Statement s = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select MAX(\"clientes\".\"cli_id\") from piloto.\"clientes\"");

            rs.next();
            //Esta es la línea del error: "No exist column MAX(piloto."clientes"."cli_id")."
            rs.getString("MAX(piloto.\"clientes\".\"cli_id\")");
            if (rs.getString("MAX(cli_id)") == null) 
            {       LabId.setText("LC001");            }
            else
            {
        long id = Long.parseLong(rs.getString("MAX(cli_id)").substring(2,rs.getString("MAX(cli_id)").length()));
        id++;
        LabId.setText("LC"+String.format("%03d", id));
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VenDatos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VenDatos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

No tengo mucha experiencia pero busco una ayuda para crear un autoincrementador que combine letras y numeros.
Espero recibir su ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Este es un sitio en español, traduce tu pregunta.

Comment: ya hice la traducción gracias por la observación @RamiroBarone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me dediqué a investigar un poco y encontré la solución por mi cuenta.

Así que sería importante que algún administrador cerrara el post y espero que a alguien le sirva la información.

Saludos.

```
//try {
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(murl+mdb,muser,mpass);            
String consulta = "select max(cli_id) from clientes";
Statement s = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(consulta);               
while(rs.next())
{                
  String lname = rs.getString(1);                
  if (lname == null) 
  {   LabId.setText("LC001"); }
  else
  {
    long id = Long.parseLong(rs.getString(1).substring(2,rs.getString(1).length()));
    id++;                
    LabId.setText("LC"+String.format("%03d", id));
  }                 
}
```